# JavaScript show loader until next page content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code below that consist of a loader and a button whenever i click my button it will direct the user to another page. What i'm trying to accomplish is i want my loader to show up only when i click my button and disappear after it goes to the other page. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```js
function lol() {
  window.location.href = "video.html";
}

var overlay = document.getElementById("transparent");
document.getElementById("uploadbtn").addEventListener("click", loader);

function loader() {

}
```

```css
.loader {
  border: 10px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 10px solid #05788C;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #05788C;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#transparent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="transparent">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <button id="uploadbtn" type="button" onclick="lol();">Click Me!</button>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not really possible because the page unloads and the next one takes over with the navigation. If you made a SPA than you have more control, but it is more complicated.

Comment: @epascarello Ermm what do you mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: @epascarello oh sorry i have edited my question above

Comment: It's possible with tricks. You show loader on each page until the whole page is loaded, and inside window.onbeforeunload handler.

Comment: @Bobby, in your edited question you're still using `location.href`. None of the additional code is really relevant as you're instructing the browser to unload the current page -- the one you want to add a loading indicator on -- and load the new page. You simply can't accomplish what you're asking for in this way.

Comment: @FissureKing I'm just trying to make it so that when the page is loading to the next page the html loader will show up until it goes to the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide your loader when the page load for the first time by set the display to none. Then after you call the lol function, the first time you need to do is to show the loader by change the display to block. That way, before redirected to another page, you loader will show up.

```js
function lol() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('loader')[0].style.display = 'block';
  window.location.href = "video.html";
}
```

```css
.loader {
  border: 10px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 10px solid #05788C;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #05788C;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#transparent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="transparent">
    <div class="loader" style="display:none"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="lol();">Click Me!</button>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Alexander ups, yup forget to add the explanation. edited the answer. thanks